# How ATG Nucleus layers modules on start up

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I want to know how ATG modules get started & are layered by Nucleus on server startup without explicitly specifying `-Datg.dynamo.modules` on server start up. I have observed that it picks up the modules in the order in which the build was done. But from where it is picking up that dynamo_module list? Till now I have found out "startNucleus.bat" where I saw `dynamo_modules` property.

```
:startNucleus
%JAVA_VM% -classpath %CLASSPATH% -Datg.dynamo.home=%NUCLEUS_HOME% -Datg.dynamo.root=%NUCLEUS_ROOT% -Datg.dynamo.server.home=%NUCLEUS_HOME% %JAVA_ARGS% atg.applauncher.dynamo.DynamoServerLauncher %DYNAMO_MODULES% %CONFIGPATH%
```

With Regards,
Nutan

Answer (score 5):

When you assemble an application, nucleus records the order in the which modules were assembled. This information is stored in a file within the EAR located @ **\atg_bootstrap.war\WEB-INF\ATG-INF**

Here there is a file named ***dynamo.env***, which is used by nucleus on server start up. You can override this configuration using *-Datg.dynamo.modules* on server start up.

Regards,
Aazim